# infer the altitude from a DTM & finally provide it to point / evincere la altitudine da un DTM & finalmente fornirla a dei punti

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, elevation

I would like to complete a point vector's table with Z data.
I am not able to take Z coordinate from a dtm
(downloaded from  http://www.regione.piemonte.it/geoscaweb/index.php?pgs2=0&pgs3=DTM10&pgs4=DTM10_f&pgs5=.zip&pgs6=%20DTM%20(passo%2010%20m)%20-%20Modello%20altezze%20filtrato%20(fogli%2050.000)&pgs8=50),
   I'm using GRASS from QGIS. All files are in its database, correctly imported.

I'm trying with v.what.rast but , even if it tells he succeeds, no new data has been recorded in the point vector's table and no new column appears.

I'm questiong about
1)the possibility of doing that with this particular DTMfile;
2)the fact that there aren't specific requirements for the point vector's table.

Comment: Here's a blog that I found on the topic http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/sampling-raster-values-at-point-locations-in-qgis/#comments  I must admit to being a little surprised that the operation wasn't a little more straightforward but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, I found that the program computed commands, but it didn't update the view of the table (allowing me to see changes) in few time even if I asked it to do it.

Comment: So a QGIS issue?

Comment: Is the table of the vector map in which you are trying to load the values connected to the database? Check with `db.tables -p` for example. You might need to add a new, empty, column in which the queried raster values will be fed (ie by using `v.db.addcolumn`).